# git fsck misses to report a tree object as unreachable

Tags: git

I'd like that git prints me all unreachable objects, not considering commits that are only reachable by reflog entries as reachable. `git fsck --unreachable --no-reflogs` misses to print a tree object which I know is unreachable. I am using git version 2.5.0.  Am I missing something?

The following is a proof that there are unreachable tree objects which fsck does not print.

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /somepath/.git/
$ echo hello >myfile
$ git add myfile
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 30a7654] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 myfile
$ echo world >>myfile
```

The following commit creates three objects: a commit, a tree and a blob:

```
$ git commit -am 2nd
[master 4b96227] 2nd
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

We make these three objects unreachable. `fsck` only reports the commit and the blob object as unreachable, but not the tree object:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD^
HEAD is now at 30a7654 initial
$ git fsck --unreachable --no-reflogs
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
unreachable commit 4b96227ebf01b6947dd5710b6494f5e92cd62d49
unreachable blob 94954abda49de8615a048f8d2e64b5de848e27a1
```

`prune` does report all three object as unreachable, including the tree object:

```
$ git reflog expire --expire=all --all
$ git prune --expire now -vn
1df502bff6e2a54e686a0a5eb4033fb6cd160ba1 tree
4b96227ebf01b6947dd5710b6494f5e92cd62d49 commit
94954abda49de8615a048f8d2e64b5de848e27a1 blob
```

Comment: Did you checked if the issue persists with git 2.8.1/2.8.2? (because of https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.6.2.txt#L7-L8, https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.6.5.txt#L35-L36, https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.7.0.txt#L269-L270)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that `git fsck` fails to report unreachable trees.  You can create additional unreachable trees using `git write-tree` with an index that you do not commit (e.g., `git add` something, then `git rm --cached` the same entry after writing the tree; or use `git update-index` to manipulate the index more directly before and after using `git write-tree`).

I *think* the Git folks consider this a feature rather than a bug, on the theory that no one cares about trees.

Note that [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fsck.html) describes the `--lost-found` flag as restoring dangling commits and blobs.  It also (experimentally) restores annotated tag objects that are delinked from their external `refs/tags/` reference, but when it does so it just writes the object name into the file name in `.git/lost-found/other/`:

```
$ cat .git/lost-found/other/9c6db16bcff193bd5a814ce5bcda40027713ed8a
9c6db16bcff193bd5a814ce5bcda40027713ed8a
$ git cat-file -t 9c6db16bcff193bd5a814ce5bcda40027713ed8a
tag
```

It would make more sense to expand the contents of the tag object, the way Git does for blob objects.  Git could even do this for trees, but just as `--unreachable` ignores them, so does `--lost-found`.

Comment: "I think the Git folks consider this a feature rather than a bug, on the theory that no one cares about trees." That would not surpise me either. +1